# How do I use checkbox event?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have created the following GUI:

[image: GUI with an TextBox (#1) to enter a machine name and a CheckBox (#2) to enable conversion of the machine name to uppercase.]

I enter my text in a `TextBox` (#1 in the picture). I have a `Button` (#2 in the picture) which should change the input in the `TextBox` to uppercase so I wrote the following code:

```cs
private void tuUpperCase(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (crossBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        machineName.Text.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why string.Replace(“X”,“Y”) works only when assigned to new string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949952/why-string-replacex-y-works-only-when-assigned-to-new-string)

Comment: @KlausGütter sI am sorry, acutally my greeting and my question got cut by the editor but I dont know why, my question was how to get the input to uppercase by clicking the checkbox But it was already answered. Thanks anyways

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think it would work too, but another User just told me an easier way but Thank you

Comment: _"another User just told me an easier way"_ -- no, not really. Another user told you the same thing that's in the proposed duplicate: `string` objects are immutable, and you _must_ assign the result of methods like `Replace()` and `ToUpper()` to a variable or property for there to be any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.ToUpper()` does not modify the string, just returns the modified string. So you need to set new modified value to the `machineName.Text`.

```
private void tuUpperCase(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (crossBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        machineName.Text = machineName.Text.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ToUpper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.ToUpper);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) method returns a **new** `string`, it does not change the `machineName.Text` property.

> Returns a copy of this string converted to uppercase.

If you assign its return value (the new uppercase `string`) to `machineName.Text` it will work.

```
machineName.Text = machineName.Text.ToUpper();
```

One issue with this is that the caret position will be reset, when the new text is set. You could store the [`CaretIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.CaretIndex);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0), modify the text and then reassign it to preserve the position.

```
private void tuUpperCase(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (crossBox.IsChecked == true)
   {
      var caretIndex = machineName.CaretIndex;
      machineName.Text = machineName.Text.ToUpper();
      machineName.CaretIndex = caretIndex;
   }
}
```

From your comment I assume that you use a `CheckBox` event like `Checked` or `Unchecked`. However, this will only convert the text to uppercase the moment you check the `CheckBox`, everthing typed afterwards is still lowercase. A solution to this would be to use the [`TextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.TextChanged);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) event of the `TextBox`, which would convert the text as you type.